# How to change a patchset and push it as a new one?

Tags: gerrit

Is it possible to fetch an existing patchset (that has not been merged into my local machine), change and push it as a new Patch Set?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813465/multiple-devs-pushing-to-same-change

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@Uncletall put all the steps there and the link, the only thing is that you should not delete the changeId and you should do a git commit --amend. I am giving him a +1.

It should be like this

1. On Gerrit, go to the review, select "checkout", on the Download field as opposed to "pull", "cherry-pick", or "patch", then copy the command.
2. On the git project paste the copied link from above

   This will create a detached head, which is a branch with no name (I've been through the desert on a horse with no name, It felt good to be out of the rain.)
3. Name that horse! `git checkout -b new_branch_name`
4. Change what you want and do a `git add` on the files you want.
5. Do `git commit --amend` and **keep** the same `Change-Id`.
6. Push your changes:

   `git push origin <new_branch_name>:refs/for/<thatgerritbranchyouwanttochange>`

Comment: I think you mean `git checkout -b <somebranchname>`. I also then had to amend author information prior to the push since the previous patch was created by someone else: `git commit --amend --author "myself <myself@me.com>"`

Comment: why not use `HEAD` instead of creating a new local branch that is not worth for anything (gerrit sadly only keeps a single commit per change any ways)

Answer (score 5):

Consult [Trying out a Change](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/intro-quick.html#_trying_out_the_change) in the official documentation.

Here is what you do:

1. Checkout the change as described in the documentation
2. Create a local branch from the FETCH_HEAD
3. Modify your code
4. Commit the change using `git --amend` and remove the `Change-Id` in the commit message
5. A new `Change-Id` will automatically be added and this will result in a new Change Set
6. Push your change for review and Gerrit will see it as a new Change Set

As pointed out by @magnus-bäck, I was describing *how to create a new Change-Set*. If you want to *add a new Patch Set to the current review* you should **NOT** remove the `Change-Id`.

Comment: This will create a new _change_, but I think what's being asked for is being table to create a new patch set _on the original change_. Removing the "remove the Change-Id line" item from the list above will address this. One could also mention that it's assumed that a Change-Id line is present in the original commit message. If it isn't, https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_replace describes what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Just follow the below steps:

1. **cherry-pick** your patch (from gerrit UI) to your machine.
2. Modify the content and run `git add <modified file>`.
3. Amend the last commit using `git commit --amend` that pops up a COMMIT-EDITMGS window. Save it accordingly.
4. Push your change to gerrit using `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch_name`

   It will create a new patch set.